# Change view value without change model value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I store my hour field in minutes in database, so I need to change the value to show in hours.

I don't have the code yet.

I thought in some alternatives and I would like to know if somebody have tried some:

**1ª** I will make a directive as attribute and pass the value as a attribute of the directive, do what I need with the value and after all put the final value, like 15:59, in the element.

**2ª** I will make a directive too, but this directive will be an element that will self control, when the user put a value, I will convert to minutes, but in the view will stay with the user input value.

What's the better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes down to whether or not you need to have user input. If you do you have to use a 2 way directive, as shown below.

Within the angular directive link function you have 4 parameters:

```
function (scope, element, attrs, controller)
```

The controller parameter allows you to manipulate the ng-model of your directive. Most importantly controller have something called $formatters, and $parsers. These $formatters and $parsers allow you to do exactly what you're trying todo, as it will allow you to manipulate Model and View values as part of your directive.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers

Formatters will allow you set how the model is viewed in the view (initial load)
Parsers will allow you to set how the view is saved to the model (user input)

This can be done as follows:

```
directive code
....
link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
   function hoursToMinutes(viewValue){
     viewValue = ...Conversion logic...
     controller.$viewValue = viewValue;
     return viewValue;
   }
   function minutesToHours(modelValue){
     modelValue= ...Conversion logic...
     controller.$modelValue= modelValue;
     return modelValue;
   }
   controller.$parsers.push(hoursToMinutes);
   controller.$formatters.push(minutesToHours);
}
....
```

Comment: From the docs the `parsers` transform the `view value`, so in the end there is a different model value. E.g. for sanitizing. The `formatters` do not change the model itself but the appearance in the DOM, just like `filters`. Can you explain why you additionally added these lines: `controller.$viewValue = viewValue;` and `controller.$modelValue= modelValue;`

Comment: Is it to adjust the other part? So if the model value changes you want to update the view and vice versa. Wouldn't then `controller.$setViewValue(viewValue); controller.$render()` be better?

Comment: $formatters run only on page load; $parsers fire on input change. If you want to change the value of the view as well as the user types, then you would need to add $setViewValue, and $render.

Answer (score 1):

create a filter

```
app.filter('minutesToHourFormatFilter', function() {
      return function(input) {
      var b = input / 60;
      var hours = b.toFixed(0);
      var c = (b - hours) * 60;
      var minutes = Math.ceil(c)
      return hours + "h " + minutes + "m"
      }
    });
```

then in your template you can do:

```
{{ minutes | minutesToHourFormatFilter}}
```