# Separating ViewValue and ModelValue in Angular for a text input

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive

I need to convert a custom element  that takes account numbers as input like *ABCD1234* and make it display as ****1234. While saving this value/submitting the form I want the value to go as *ABCD1234* ie the true value. I have tried making use of $formatters but it seems to be changing the model value as well and saving the * in the value.

How do I separate the view value and model value so that the users see only last 4 digits but form saves true value entered.

The regex looks for all but last four digit and replaces with *

```js
'use strict';
// @ngdoc directive
// @description
// directive for masking NPI(Non-public Information) inputs with asterisks.

angular.module('MyAPP').directive('npiMask', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(inputValue) {
                var transformedInput = inputValue.toString().replace(/.(?=.{4,}$)/g, '*');
                if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<input-text
    name="accountNum"
    label="{{'LOAN_REPAY.ADD_LOAN.ACCOUNT_NUM_LABEL' | translate}}"
    ng-model="vm.model.formData.loanDetails.accountNum"
    is-required="true"
    maxlength="35"
    locked="vm.isSummaryView"
    size="4"
    ui-mask
    npi-mask
>
```

[Change view value without change model value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295021/change-view-value-without-change-model-value)

^ this did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this:

```js
'use strict';

// @ngdoc directive

// @description

// directive for masking NPI(Non-public Information) inputs with asterisks.


angular.module('myApp').directive('npiMask', 'constants', function(constants) {

    return {

        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function($scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

            var temp = '';

            element.on('focusin', function() {

                element[0].querySelector('#' + modelCtrl.$name).value = temp;

            });

            element.on('focusout', function() {

                temp = modelCtrl.$modelValue;

                var transformedInput = temp.toString().replace(constants.patterns.spacesInTheEnd, '*');

                element[0].querySelector('#' + modelCtrl.$name).value = transformedInput;

            });

        }

    };

});
```